# Bidirectional 100% stacked bar chart in R

Tags: database, bar-chart, bidirectional

I have the following data<

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eltSm.png)

which I want to plot on a bidirectional 100% stacked bar chart in a way that the data for the 'stem' is upward of the x-axis and the 'root' is downward. The 12 treatment FT_IR are the same for both, but I want to visualize the data in a way that in the bar there is the percentage of the EWXA+LWXA.

While in excel this is simple, in R i have encountered several issue. Bar charts in horizontal instead of vertical way and I also could not change the order of EWXA and LWXA (for stem EWXA below and for root above).